# CATIA Script to Rename All Objects in Specification Tree

Tags: vba, catia

I am looking for a CATIA script to replace the names of all objects in the specification tree of a CATPart with a constant string suffixed by a running number. As an example, consider the following specification tree before renaming (left picture) and after the script run (right picture):

[image: original specification tree]
[image: specification tree with renamed objects]

Background is the removal of sensitive information (such as part numbers of electronics components) for preparation of a STEP export of a large assembly.

Answer (score 0):

Well this certainly is not a hard one to write and figure out. As I understand StackOwerflow is not a site where you get a code on demand but a site where you get help with your code.

I will give you a hint. What you are looking for are collections of objects which holds features, bodys, constrains etc. and iterate trough all these collections and change the names.

I would start recording macro when you manually change the names, then take a look at the script and learn from it.